# Is there a way to make a command where it finds the argument entered in a JSON File, and send all the results in a Discord Embed?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

So basically, I'm trying to make this command where the user enters in an argument in this case the name of a state. Once the user has entered an argument, the client looks inside the voter.json file and finds each dict with the state that is the same as the argument. Once finished, it put the results on a discord embed then sends it to the user. Problem is that, the code works but, it will send a separate embed with each dict that the client found. I want it to send the dicts all in the same embed.

main.py

```py
@client.command(name='search')
async def search(context, *, user):
  with open('votes.json','r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


    for officials in data['officials']:
      o_name = officials["name"]
      o_state = officials["state"]

      if o_state == user:
        myEmbed = discord.Embed(color=0xd4af37)
        myEmbed.add_field(name=o_state, value="".join(o_name))

        await context.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

votes.json

```json
{
  "officials" :[
    {
      "name": "RestiveSole267",
      "state": "Anchorage"
    },
    {
      "name":"Avia_JP",
      "state": "Anchorage"
    },
    {
      "name":"BillBobj",
      "state":"Anchorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

output:

```
1st Embed:
RestiveSole267

2nd Embed:
Avia_JP

3rd Embed:
BillBobj
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to accomplish your goal.

```
x = {
  "officials" :[
    {
        'BuddyBob':10,
        'Guy':True
    },
    {
        'BuddyGirl':13,
        'Guy':False
    },
    {
        'BuddyBobo':15,
        'Guy':True
    }
  ]
}

for official in x['officials']:
    if official["Guy"]==True:
        print(official)
```

output:

```
{'BuddyBob': 10, 'Guy': True}
{'BuddyBobo': 15, 'Guy': True}
```